# SQL Server 2005, Foreign key check against part of a table

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2005, foreign-key

I have an `articles` table that references a `categories` table.  I'm defining the foreign key like this:

```
constraint fk_categoryid foreign key (categoryid) references categories (categoryid)
on update no action
on delete no action
```

Is it possible in the foreign key definition to restrict the categories that can be referenced based on another column in the `categories` table?  For example, say there is a `hasarticles` column in the `categories` table.  I'd like the foreign key constraint to be restricted to those categories where `hasarticles = true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this isn't possible.

I'd probably create a separate table `categoriesWithArticles` that holds the relevant `categoryid`s (instead of having the flag) and have the FK reference that table instead.

Another more convoluted way to enforce it and keep the column would be

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
categoryId int primary key,
hasarticles bit not null,
unique(categoryId, hasarticles)
)

CREATE TABLE articles
(
categoryId int,
hasarticles as cast (1 as bit) persisted,
FOREIGN KEY (categoryId, hasarticles) REFERENCES categories(categoryId, hasarticles)
)
```

But this requires the creation of a technically redundant unique constraint as well as the additional persisted column in the `articles` table.